# $\int_e^{e^4}\sqrt{\log (x)} dx = ? $ given that $\int_1^2 e^{x^2}dx=\alpha$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$\int_e^{e^4}\sqrt{\log (x)}\,dx = ?  $ given that $\int_1^2 e^{x^2}dx=\alpha$.
 The answer given in here is $2e^4-e-\alpha$
I did a substitution $y=\sqrt{\log(x)}$ to convert the integral into $\int_1^22y^2e^{y^2}dy$. Now if we try substitution $u=y^2$, I get an integral of the form $\int e^u\sqrt{u}\,du$. I feel there must be a much better way to get the answer by relating it to the $\alpha$.

Hints are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use integrations by parts: $$\int_1^22y^2e^{y^2}dy=ye^{y^2}\Big|_{y=1}^{y=2}-\int_1^2e^{y^2}dy$$